# Android show google map problem!

Tags: java, android, exception, google-maps

Hi *
I need to show a map by passing the address. however, in some cases, the whole app will be forced to close. it may be because of gecoding the address to coordinate. My question is what is the best way to handle the exception while calling the map? The following function is my function for getting the gecoder results.however, it is still not perfect. what should i do in order to avoid the shut down of the app? thanks a lot!!
penny

```
private void findLocation(final String locationName) {
    Thread thrd = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void interrupt() {
            super.interrupt();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 2);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                MyLog.e(e.getMessage());
            }

            uiCallback.sendEmptyMessage(0);

        }
    };
    thrd.start();
}
```

Comment: Tip: don't use a raw Thread, use an AsyncTask instead. For one thing you won't need things like uiCallback.

Comment: Think about using the AsyncTask class instead of a custom thread. It's much easier, as you don't have to handle the whole UI-Thread Worker-Thread thing by yourself. And as ddewaele said, post a stack trace so we can see what happened exactly.

Comment: Thanks!! i am trying to doing this

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your app is crashing due to a RuntimeException.
Can you add a stacktrace of the actual crash ? 
Your code only handles the IOException by logging it.
If another (Runtime)Exception occurs, your app can still crash as it's not properly handled.